# How to handle links with MVC 'Area' sections

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have developed a project in C# MVC with 'AdminLte' Template and I uses Areas for submodules.

when I access a link from home page (http://localhost:9760/Home/Index) the it works perfectly as follows [http://localhost:9760/Manage/ChangePassword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZxX0.jpg)

but when I access the same link from Area ex: 'AirSurveillance' [http://localhost:9760/AirSurveillance/Manage/ChangePassword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp5pQ.jpg) it is not working and gives 404 error because it tried to find 'Manage' controller (which is not there) in 'AirSurveillance' area.

this is my auto-generated 'SecurityClearanceAreaRegistration.cs' file

```
namespace IIMS.Areas.SecurityClearance
{
    public class SecurityClearanceAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "SecurityClearance";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "SecurityClearance_default",
                "SecurityClearance/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using areas, your links will need to specify the area for the controller/action you're pointing to. If you want to use controllers outside of those areas you specify a blank Area. for example...

```
@Html.ActionLink("ChangePassword", "Manage", new { Area = ""})
```

Comment: Thank you very much kd345205, it was really helpful